# subtract one day from timestamp - python

Tags: python, python-3.x

'I'm trying to subtract a day from this date 1590074712 in order to make 1590008151 but can't figure out any way to achieve that.

I've tried with:

```
from datetime import datetime

ts= 1590074712 
date = datetime.timestamp(ts) - timedelta(days = 1)
print(date)
```

How can I subtract a day from a date in the above format?

## I want the output in timestamp

Comment: If you're starting with a timestamp, can you just subtract 86400 - the number of seconds in a day - from it?

Comment: yes, it worked for me thank you @SimonBrahan

Answer (score 5):

Use [`datetime.fromtimestamp()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp):

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

ts= 1590074712
date = datetime.fromtimestamp(ts) - timedelta(days = 1)
print(date)
```

Prints:

```
2020-05-20 15:25:12
```